# NavigationManager LocationChanged event is not triggering when navigating to a page outside of my website

Tags: blazor

In one of my Blazor pages, I am polling a service periodically to refresh data on the screen.

When the user navigates away from the page, I want to stop the polling process.

To achieve this goal I'm attempting to use NavigationManager.LocationChanged event.

Here is the relevant code:

```c#
@inject NavigationManager navManager

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    navManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
    base.OnInitialized();
}

void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsTaskCancelled = true; 
}

async Task RefreshPage()
{
    while (IsTaskCancelled == false)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            await myService.GetLatestData();
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Ended Data Collection.");
}
```

This code works if my user navigates to a different page in the site.

But it does NOT work if the user clicks a link that goes to a page outside of the site.

For example if user clicks a link like below

```
<li><a href="https:www.microsoft.com">About</a></li>
```

The LocationChanged event will not trigger, and the polling code keeps humming along even though my webpage is no longer visible.

Can NavigationManager support this capability, and if so what would I need to change to make it work?

As an alternative I am thinking to write some js code to callback into my page to reset the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top section, add

```
@implements IDisposable
```

and in @code :

```
public void Dispose()
{
    IsTaskCancelled = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Disposed.");
}
```

You can then remove the navManager, Dispose() will fire for internal and external URLs.

Comment: I would consider a Timer instead of the endless loop. But you have to Dispose() a Timer too, that stays.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Thanks for the additional suggestion!